# How to query data in Excel from Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio-2013, office-automation

**Background:**

I am transferring data from one Excel document `doc0` to a templated Excel document `doc1` to speed up processes at work. My only real restriction is that I cannot modify the document's formatting, so regular VBA is not an option. I can only pull data out of `doc0` modify it and place it in `doc1`. I am using Visual Studio 2013 for doing so.

**What I need to do is:**

> 1. Organize `doc0` numerically by Col 1 first, then Col 3 second. Then place the top 10 results in a specific cell range in `doc1`.
> 2. Get a count for jobs assigned to each worker and return that result to Visual Studio. Worker names are listed in Col 4.

I know how to query using SQL, but am open to using other functions/languages that can perform the same task.

**Question:**

> How can I query the data to perform the actions above?

A simple example can be seen with the link below. The blue represents `doc0`, the red the results to be displayed in `doc1` and the green is the results that I need to have returned to corresponding textboxes in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: Why is it ok for someone to edit my post without a confirmation that it is ok by me? ->everything marked is fine, but things like me not being able to even post the picture, because my ranking on here is too low is kind of ridiculous when someone else can come in and add it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. ADO.NET is able to connect to your excel sheet using OleDB to read data with simple query capability. [Examples can be found in KB316934](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316934).

Connect to an Excel file to read and write data:

### Connection String

To access an Excel workbook by using the Jet OLE DB Provider, use a connection string that has the following syntax:

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"

Depending on your excel version, the connection string may slightly differ. [Look them up here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2013/). E.g. 2013 would look like:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
>   Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

### Read and write data

- Use the sheet name followed by a dollar sign (for example, [Sheet1$] or [My Worksheet$]). A workbook table that is referenced in this manner includes the whole used range of the worksheet.

  > select * from [Sheet1$]
- Use a range with a defined name (for example, [MyNamedRange]):

  > Select * from [MyNamedRange]
- Use a range with a specific address (for example, [Sheet1$A1:B10]):

  > Select * from [Sheet1$A1:B10]

Writing is done in a similar matter if you're using OleDB

> INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (F1, F2) values ('111', 'ABC')
>
> UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F2 = 'XYZ' WHERE F1 = '111'

You may need to create a temporary copy from which you can query data, as you may be reading and writing to the documents using different techniques.

Full example at the link (unfortunately in VB.NET).

### Alternative solutions

If you really want full fidelity access to the Excel file, without depending on Excel being present or running, you could also investigate:

- [Excel Package Plus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)
- [NPIO](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)
- [Aspose Cells.NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx) (commercial)

These packages do not support querying, so you'll need to extract the data into objects and use Linq-to-Objects to query/sort the data before writing it back to the files.

Comment: This solution is too old, was for Excel 2003. I'm using 2013. Good try though.

Comment: Trick remains the same, only the connection string slightly differs.

Comment: Do you know ADO.NET OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, OleDbDataReader. It's all the same as accessing SQL Server, just use the connection string above.

Comment: 1. I don't know the details of the diffs between vb and vb.net to hash out the problems 2. The key words for your solution are no longer available in the library, so the connection string above does not work.